# How to Reload a Python3 C extension module?

Tags: module, python-3.x, reload

I wrote a C extension (mycext.c) for Python 3.2. The extension relies on constant data stored in a C header (myconst.h). The header file is generated by a Python script. In the same script, I make use of the recently compiled module. The workflow in the Python3 myscript (not shown completely) is as follows:

```
configure_C_header_constants() 
write_constants_to_C_header() # write myconst.h
os.system('python3 setup.py install --user') # compile mycext
import mycext
mycext.do_stuff()
```

This works perfectly fine the in a Python session for the first time. If I repeat the procedure in the same session (for example, in two different testcases of a unittest), the first compiled version of mycext is always (re)loaded.

How do I effectively reload a extension module with the latest compiled version?

Comment: It's not exactly constant if you need to change it all the time... Put the constants in a configuration file.

Comment: They will be constant in the real application (it will not use Python). I use Python to generate the constants and unittest the C code.

Comment: Make a config file until you have figured out what the constants should be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am testing an algorithm, the constants are application specific (I cannot know them before hand). From my incomplete problem description it is not clear why I cannot do it the way you suggest. The answer provided by Sven does exactly what I want, though.

Comment: Indeed, it is not clear, because there is no reason. You *can* do it that way, I promise. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<s>You can reload modules in Python 3.x by using the [`imp.reload()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/imp.html#imp.reload) function.  (This function used to be a built-in in Python 2.x.  Be sure to read the documentation -- there are a few caveats!)</s>

Python's import mechanism will never `dlclose()` a shared library.  Once loaded, the library will stay until the process terminates.

Your options (sorted by decreasing usefulness):

1. Move the module import to a subprocess, and call the subprocess again after recompiling, i.e. you have a Python script `do_stuff.py` that simply does

   ```
   import mycext
   mycext.do_stuff()
   ```

   and you call this script using

   ```
   subprocess.call([sys.executable, "do_stuff.py"])
   ```
2. Turn the compile-time constants in your header into variables that can be changed from Python, eliminating the need to reload the module.
3. Manually `dlclose()` the library after deleting all references to the module (a bit fragile since you don't hold all the references yourself).
4. Roll your own import mechanism.

   Here is an example how this can be done.  I wrote a minimal Python C extension `mini.so`, only exporting an integer called `version`.

   ```
   >>> import ctypes
   >>> libdl = ctypes.CDLL("libdl.so")
   >>> libdl.dlclose.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
   >>> so = ctypes.PyDLL("./mini.so")
   >>> so.PyInit_mini.argtypes = []
   >>> so.PyInit_mini.restype = ctypes.py_object 
   >>> mini = so.PyInit_mini()
   >>> mini.version
   1
   >>> del mini
   >>> libdl.dlclose(so._handle)
   0
   >>> del so
   ```

   At this point, I incremented the version number in `mini.c` and recompiled.

   ```
   >>> so = ctypes.PyDLL("./mini.so")
   >>> so.PyInit_mini.argtypes = []
   >>> so.PyInit_mini.restype = ctypes.py_object 
   >>> mini = so.PyInit_mini()
   >>> mini.version
   2
   ```

   You can see that the new version of the module is used.

   For reference and experimenting, here's `mini.c`:

   ```
   #include <Python.h>

   static struct PyModuleDef minimodule = {
      PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "mini", NULL, -1, NULL
   };

   PyMODINIT_FUNC
   PyInit_mini()
   {
       PyObject *m = PyModule_Create(&minimodule);
       PyModule_AddObject(m, "version", PyLong_FromLong(1));
       return m;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, `imp.reload(mypythonmod)` works fine for Python modules, but I am dealing with a C extension module. `imp.reload(mycext)` still reloads the originally imported version of the extension module.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on option 1. I have no experience whatsoever with subprocesses. I tried `subprocess.call(['import', 'mycext'])` and the interpreter stays idle. Tried `subprocess.Popen(['import', 'mycext']`, how do I then call `mycext.do_stuff()`?

Comment: @user1069152: Edited my answer.

Comment: Option 4 works perfectly. Option 1 gets complex when do_stuff requires input and output arguments.

Comment: @user1069152: Well, option 4 is quite a hack and not very portable.  To make the more robust option 1 work, you could use the `pickle` module to pipe the arguments to the subprocess and get the return values back.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way, set a new module name, import it, and change reference to it.

Comment: Could you clarify or maybe give an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update: I have now created a Python library around this approach:

- https://github.com/bergkvist/creload
- https://pypi.org/project/creload/

---

Rather than using the `subprocess` module in Python, you can use `multiprocessing`. This allows the child process to inherit all of the memory from the parent (on UNIX-systems).

For this reason, you also need to be careful not to import the C extension module into the parent.

If you return a value that depends on the C extension, it might also force the C extension to become imported in the parent as it receives the return-value of the function.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys


def subprocess_call(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    """Executes a function in a forked subprocess"""
    
    ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    q = ctx.Queue(1)
    is_error = ctx.Value('b', False)
    
    def target():
        try:
            q.put(fn(*args, **kwargs))
        except BaseException as e:
            is_error.value = True
            q.put(e)
    
    ctx.Process(target=target).start()
    result = q.get()    
    if is_error.value:
        raise result
    
    return result


def my_c_extension_add(x, y):
    assert 'my_c_extension' not in sys.modules.keys()
    # ^ Sanity check, to make sure you didn't import it in the parent process

    import my_c_extension
    return my_c_extension.add(x, y)


print(subprocess_call(my_c_extension_add, 3, 4))
```

If you want to extract this into a decorator - for a more natural feel, you can do:

```py
class subprocess:
    """Decorate a function to hint that it should be run in a forked subprocess"""
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return subprocess_call(self.fn, *args, **kwargs)


@subprocess
def my_c_extension_add(x, y):
    assert 'my_c_extension' not in sys.modules.keys()
    # ^ Sanity check, to make sure you didn't import it in the parent process

    import my_c_extension
    return my_c_extension.add(x, y)


print(my_c_extension_add(3, 4))
```

This can be useful if you are working in a Jupyter notebook, and you want to rerun some function without rerunning all your existing cells.

### Notes

This answer might only be relevant on Linux/macOS where you have a `fork()` system call:

- [Python multiprocessing linux windows difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148344/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows-difference)
- https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/