# How do get import/reload to recompile changed Cython imported by a module I reload?

Tags: python-2.7, cython, python-import

How do I ensure that changed Cython code is recompiled when a module that imports it is reloaded into a Python session?

For example in `utils.pyx` I have something like

```
def func(int x):
    return x**2
```

while in `test.py` I have, for example something like

```
def test_cython():

    import pyximport; pyximport.install()
    import utils

    return utils.func(5)
```

I would like to work in IPython and have any changes to `utils.pyx` cause a recompilation whenever I reload `test.py` there, but

```
import test
```

seems to do nothing if `test.py` has already been imported and

```
reload(test)
```

loads from the already compiled `test.pyc`, so that even if `utils.pyx` has been changed

```
test.test_cython()
```

uses the "old" version of `utils.func`.

It seems the only way to achieve this is to make an edit to `test.py` after each change to `utils.pyx`. Is there any other way to do this?

---

Note: I believe this is a slightly different issue from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17955194/656912); in particular, [this promising answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18134343/656912), does not solve the problem for me, even when I take the `import` and `pyximport.install` statements out of `test_cython` and place them at the top level of `test.py`.

Comment: See [reload() is broken for C extension objects](http://bugs.python.org/issue1144263) and the answer to [How to Reload a Python3 C extension module?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8295590/4279), try [Reloading a Python extension module from IPython](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18266786/4279) using [Kernel in a separate process](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/overview.html#ipythonzmq).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Those all look a bit messy. Is the short answer simply: C extensions are hard to get rid of, so it's best to just run from the command line or (re)start a new Python/IPython instance.

Comment: in short: [use two process configuration](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/overview.html#ipythonzmq). It makes it trivial to restart Kernel process that allows to load updated C extension versions. For you it would look like the reload works.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That makes sense, but I don't have Qt, so it's a bit less straightforward for me. Any idea what the equivalent would be on OS X (without using the "notebook" interface)?

Comment: why do you think that you need Qt? Try `ipython notebook`, `ipython console`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Going through the steps to use `ipython console` including how to get `reload` to work in that context sounds like it would be an answer.