# Python[3.9] Windows vs Linux multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-multiprocessing, python-3.9

I have the following code, which I was working on Linux, which worked perfectly.

It would read a DB, load it in memory with SQLite3 and then ask all the cores to select and see if they find such information on the DB(read-only).

If they did or didn't, then the next value would be selected through multiprocessing.lock so that each core/thread would have a unique value(make sure that no two threads ask the same question).

In total, the python script would use up around 3-4GB of RAM and all threads (16) on Linux(Ubuntu).

On windows, the same code loads up 16 different DBs (taking 50+GB of ram), and it doesn't respect the multiprocessing.lock value.

Below is the code, which I have simplified but tested and still works the same way.

Do you know how I can achieve the same result in windows?

Code and outputs below:

```
import multiprocessing.shared_memory
import sqlite3
import time

threadLock = multiprocessing.Lock()

firstValueer = multiprocessing.shared_memory.ShareableList(['5'])

DATABASE = r'DB.sql'
t0 = time.time()
db_path = r'DB.db'
source = sqlite3.connect(db_path)

connection= sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared", uri=True,check_same_thread=False)
source.backup(connection)
connected = connection.cursor()

t01 = time.time()
total = t01 - t0
print("loading DB:", total)


def select(varA,varB,varC,varD):
    connected.execute("SELECT 1 FROM tableA where var in (?,?,?,?)" ,(varA,varB,varC,varD))
    data = connected.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        value = 0
    else:
        value = 1
    return value

def getNextValue():
    global firstValueer
    with threadLock:
        tmpint = int(firstValueer[0])
        tmpint += 1
        firstValueer[0] = str(tmpint)
        return int(firstValueer[0])

def main(firstValue):
    while firstValue < 100:
        print (firstValue)
        firstValue = getNextValue()
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1 - t0
    print("with CPU:", total)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for cpu in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        multiprocessing.Process(target = main, args = (getNextValue(), )).start()
```

Windows output(PyCharm)

```
loading DB: 0.001062154769897461
loading DB: 0.0016663074493408203
6
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0048923492431640625
loading DB: 0.0010585784912109375
7
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
loading DB:71
 0.0005996227264404297
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
9
80
81
682

83
7
84
85
8
86
987

88
10
89
11
90
12
91
92
13
93
94
14
95
15
16
96
17
97
18
98
19
99
20
with CPU: 0.00489377975463867221

22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.004536867141723633
loading DB: 0.0010526180267333984
8
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.004870176315307617
loading DB: 0.0011360645294189453
11
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0038933753967285156
loading DB: 0.0016775131225585938
10
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.004441499710083008
loading DB: 0.0
13
loading DB: 0.00109124183654785166

7
8
9
10
12
11
6
7
812

13
9
14
10
15
11
16
12
17
13
14
18
15
1619

20
21
17
22
1823

19
2420

2125

22
26
23
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
2434

35
25
36
26
37
27
38
28
39
29
40
30
41
31
42
32
43
33
44
34
45
35
46
47
4836

49
37
50
38
51
39
52
40
53
41
54
42
55
43
5644

5745

58
46
59
47
60
48
61
49
62
50
63
51
64
65
52
66
5367

54
68
55
69
70
56
71
57
72
58
73
59
74
60
75
61
76
62
77
63
78
64
79
65
80
66
81
67
82
68
83
69
84
70
85
71
86
72
87
73
88
74
89
75
90
76
91
77
92
78
93
79
94
80
9581

82
83
96
84
97
85
98
86
87
99
88
with CPU:89 
0.00487518310546875
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.00487518310546875
loading DB: 0.0010840892791748047
15
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0032472610473632812
loading DB: 0.0
14
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0027418136596679688
loading DB: 0.0011019706726074219
17
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.003863811492919922
loading DB: 0.0010428428649902344
16
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0026226043701171875
loading DB: 0.0
19
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
loading DB: 0.001070261001586914
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
18
92
93
94
6
95
796

97
8
98
999

with CPU: 10
0.002686738967895508
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.003235340118408203
loading DB: 0.0010516643524169922
20
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0020956993103027344
loading DB: 0.0010623931884765625
21
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0027017593383789062

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Linux output:

```
loading DB: 0.0004832744598388672
6
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
7
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
with CPU: 0.0084991455078125
with CPU: 0.011128902435302734
with CPU: 0.012439250946044922
82
with CPU: 0.012716293334960938
8
with CPU: 0.013614892959594727

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why don't you use a proper database? What you describe is *extremely* inefficient even in Linux. SQLite is an embedded database, *not* meant for concurrent operations. Python's multiprocessing works by starting multiple processes instead of multiple threads, which means each process would need its own copy of the data. What you describe is probably a difference in SQLite implementations, not multiprocessing

Comment: SQLite has very rudimentary indexing, query engine and buffering. And definitely no parallelism/concurrency mechanisms. A server-based database on the other hand has all of these.

Comment: [From the cache mode docs](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html): `If shared-cache mode is enabled and a thread establishes multiple connections to the same database, the connections share a single data and schema cache.`. You aren't using a single thread with many connections though. You're starting a separate SQLite instance on each process

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148344/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows-difference) doesn't answer your question, but it underlies the problem, each process created has to run the main file, and create a new database in memory and a new lock, so each process has a separate lock, and the lock is now obsolete,
maybe the lock problem is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557686/python-sharing-a-lock-between-processes) and you can try passing the database link inside an argument to the work process ... i am not an SQlite expert, but there has to be a workaround.

Comment: Hello, SQLite is due to necessity of portability. I can just copy around the script with the DB on the folder and go to different pcs and start it. As to the rest the problem is not just with SQL but also with the simple integer increment. if you check the linux incrementation it starts from 5(6) and goes by 1 all the way to 100. in Windows 6 is repeated 16 times, 7 is repeated 17 times and so on and so forth. Its not a difference in SQLite implementations(could ALSO be one)

Comment: @AhmedMohamedAEK that actually helped me a lot. i had the feeling that something wasnt going well with the forking of the process and that the if==main isnt correctly called but the post you linked helped me a lot.